# Change Site Background Image on Menu Hover

Tags: jquery, background, hover

I have been sorting through as many posts as I can but I am not finding a solution.
CSS isn't likely because of the nesting needs as you can only affect child classes/ids.

Here is what I need...
I need to have my main navigation in place. Each nav button will have its own class.
When you hover over a menu item, the main site background (body bg) will need to change.

I believe this can be done with JQuery but I don't know enough to even get started.

Example:

```
Menu Item 1 (class - .menu-item-1)
```

on `Hover` of `.menu-item-1`

change body background from `#fff` to

```
body{background-image: url('yadayadayada.jpg');}
```

And then...when the hover affect is over...go back to white.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, try

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $('.menu-item-1').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("yadayadayada.jpg")')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a8C6T/)

Comment: so why you use `var $body = $('body');` instead of calling $('body') as normal ?

Comment: @AhmadAnas since the the object might be used multiple times it is cached

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are finding. My approach is as follows:

1) Made two div's(i.e. .bg1 and .bg2) width and height covering the whole page of the screen along with two different Backgrounds.

2) Made the third one for Content.

3) Gave z-index:0 to div containing background and z-index:2 to content div

[JSFiddle : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8C6T/60/)

**HTML**

```
<span class="bg bg1 hide"></span>
<span class="bg bg2 hide"></span>
<div class="content">
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item-2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.content
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    margin:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
}

.bg
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0%;
    z-index:0;
}

.bg1
{
    display:block;
    background:url(http://mooxidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Free-Polygonal-Low-Poly-Background-2.png) no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
}

.bg2
{
    display:block;
    background:url(http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/58345.EFlLy.3e949596209919be54cb61f243defd4b.png) no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
}

.hide{display:none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.menu-item-1').hover(function(){
        $(".bg1").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(".bg1").fadeOut();
    })
    $('.menu-item-2').hover(function(){
        $(".bg2").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(".bg2").fadeOut();
    })
})
```